# Accept Both UIButtons and UIViews as parameters for method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I write a function that will take either a UIView or a UIButton as a parameter.

For example, let's say I wanted to round the corners the View/Button:

```
[self roundCorners:x]
```

How could I make that accept both a UIButton object or a UIView object as x?

My first thoughts were use id or NSObject, but I don't think that is correct:

```
-(void)roundCorners:(id)objectToRound;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`, so your method will take either one if you declare it this way:

```
- (void)roundCorners:(UIView *)objectToRound;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

```
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) view;
    // do something funky with button


} else {
   // do something funky with view

}
```

**Detailed answer:**

First of all, it is usually **best** to have a specific method to handle each class of object. This is so you can have the compiler resolve potentially passing the wrong class to a method. There are however times when this is not appropriate or possible.

UIView and UIButton are both ultimately a descendant of **NSObject**.

NSObject has a method `isKindOfClass:` which you can use to determine what you are dealing with. I have taken it a step further by defining a few helper macros that simplify these sorts of tasks, which are sometimes quite laborious.

If you have a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351967/830899)... you will see source code for, and an example of using these macros. I often use one of these macros (`asClass`), which combines a `isKindOfClass:` test linked to a type cast to the class being tested for.

You can code such a thing long hand, however I find it creates more readable code to use the `asClass` macro. Put simply `asClass(myView,UIButton)` will either resolve to nil or to a type cast reference to myView as a UIButton - if it is not a UIButton, it will be resolved to nil.

I have modified a snippet from that post to suit your question:

```
- (void)myMethod:(UIView*)view{

    UIButton *button = asClass(view, UIButton);

    if (button) {
       // do something funky with button

    } else {
       // do something funky with view

    }

}
```

To code this long hand, (without macros) it would look **approximately** like this:

```
- (void)myMethod:(UIView*)view{


    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       UIButton *button = (UIButton *) view;
       // do something funky with button


    } else {
       // do something funky with view

    }

}
```

As you can see, it's not too much extra code to do it long hand, and if you are not comfortable using macros for things like this (some people aren't) then you may choose to stick with the second example.

If you are comfortable with macros, and can see the merits of the approach I have taken, consider this third way of doing it:

```
- (void)myMethod:(UIView*)view{

    UIButton *button;

    if ( (button = asClass(view, UIButton)) ) {
       // do something funky with button

    } else {
       // do something funky with view

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it should work just fine, `id` will accept almost anything.

Comment: But if I try to access the object's bounds using objectToRound.bounds, I get an error that says "Property 'bounds' not found on object of type '__strong id'"

Comment: @Jaden10 You should cast `id` to the appropriate pointer type like this: `((UIView *)objectToRound).bounds = ...`. That said, it's easier to change the method signature as in the answer provided by _rob mayoff_.